# Oracle - Create two tables of different schema with same name in same table space. Is it valid? Does not produce any errors?

Tags: oracle, schema, tablespace

I Understand that we can have tables with same name as long as they are in different schema. Let say, both schema tables are dumped to same tablespace even then it is valid? I think as per my knowledge it is valid.. Is my understanding correct? Or is there any clause in this scenario? or any other issues?

Comment: This should work fine.  Have a nice day.

Comment: thanks :-) Good day to you too :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly valid.

The namespaces in an Oracle database are schemas.  Tablespaces are solely related to physical storage of segments.  You can't have two tables with the same name in the same schema but you can have as many tables with the same name in the same tablespace.